# One to Many Biometric Identification Matching for Android?

Tags: android, biometrics

I am currently searching for a method for one to many (1:N) biometric identification for fingerprint, face, Iris or voice.
The match certainty is not that important as the problem is more for a deterrent rather then perfection. Ideally the matching could happen offline. Seperate hardware for the scanning would not be an issue.

So far the SDK's I have come across only do one-to-one for example:
https://www.supremainc.com/en/AccessControl-TimeandAttendance/SDK/BioMini-SDK-Android

So it just may not be possible with existing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you have to  use  opencv library which is perfect for biometric identification.